# Google Sheets plotting time series out of order

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to create a simple line chart in Google Sheets but it is plotting my time series out of order for some reason. The first data point is 12:01 a.m. on a given date, with my last data point representing 12:00 a.m. on the following day. However, you can see in the first image below that it's plotting the time series out of sequence for some reason. My time column is formatted as time.

[image: Out of sequence plot]

If I select 'treat labels as text', it plots the time series in the correct order but I end up with way more labels on the x-axis than I want and can't figure out how to change that.

[image: Plot with correct time series order but too many labels]

Comment: HI. I'm sorry, I'm confused about exactly what is your question. By the looks of your 2nd graph, it seems as though you have solved the basic graphing problem. So is the issue just limited to : `but I end up with way more labels on the x-axis than I want`?

Comment: Related question (Web Applications:) [How to reduce number of X axis labels?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/136386/196152). This has the **exact** answer to your question.

Comment: format your time column as hh:mm instead of h:mm am/pm, then do the "treat as text"?